# Balancing LVM Virtual group between disks

Tags: lvm

I have an LVM virtual group with 4x disks, on this virtual group there are several logical volumes. However all the logical volumes have been placed on the first disk in the group resulting in poor performance.
It it possible to rebalance the logical volumes so that they are spread roughly evenly over the 4 disks?

Answer (score 6):

To balance the spread of LV on all disks you can execute command like this:

```
lvconvert --stripes 4 vg/lv01
```

This will stripe the LV `lv01` to all 4 disks.

Also you can consider change the stripe size (depend a lot of type of data you store on this LV)

```
lvconvert -I 64k vg/lv01
```

P.S. moving around LV on different PV rarely will help.

Comment: Does it rebalance immediately and automatically? Or does it only apply to new data written?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, when you execute the command it rebalance the data (it take some time)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pvmove` to move LVs from one PV to another:

```
pvmove -n <logical_volume> <pv_from> <pv_to>
```

so for example

```
pvmove -n lvol1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

to move `lvol1` from `sdb1` to `sdc1`.